# Is it possible to extract same field with two different name through regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract few fields from log file using regex. my regex is working fine. I just want that one of the extracted field associate with two different name.

[My Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lmtp8r/1)

In above example, I want that extracted field "cms_relative_time" is also named as "relative time". that means, both relative_time and cms_relative_time should refer to same value.

first of all,I am not sure if its possible in regex. I tried few things like copy the same code and replace name but its not working.

```
(?P<cms_relative_time>\d+\.\d+)(?P<relative_time>\d+\.\d+)
```

Comment: Once a match has consumed a portion of the input, it cannot be consumed again.  But, what language are you using?  Couldn't you just reuse the same capture group?

Comment: Try [`(?P<relative_time>(?P<cms_relative_time>\d+\.\d+))`](https://regex101.com/r/XbJNSK/1)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: I am using in SPLUNK Application. not language specific. unfortunately, i can't use same name as relative_time conatins other data with cms and cms_relative_time is specific for cms logs.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: it worked. Cheers :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may put a named capturing group inside another:

```
(?P<relative_time>(?P<cms_relative_time>\d+\.\d+))
|                 |                             ||
|                 |---------- Group 2 ----------||
|------------------ Group 1 ---------------------|
```

See your [updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/XbJNSK/1).